# Outsourcing UI/UX while keeping the app code secret

Tags: bitbucket, angular-material, user-experience

I would like to outsource some UI/UX work to professional Designers while focusing on developing my web app. How can I supply some rough views and templates to work on to the designer while keeping the code inaccessible to the designer?
I use Bitbucket and Jira.

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a technical solution to a nontechnical problem. Don't worry about keeping the code inaccessible to the designer. Make sure you have a good strong contract and NDA and work with somebody trustworthy. You'll get better design if the designer actually knows what they're working on.

Comment: If it's just UI/UX, you could consider outsourcing the design using collaborative design tools such as UXPin or InVision as the platform.